# Error al pasar de un Array de string a otro de Fechas C#

Tags: c#, datetime

El error me da dentro del bucle `for`, necesito que la fecha entre con el formato de "días/meses/años horas:minutos".

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strfechas = Request.QueryString["date"];

    char separator = ',';
    string[] fechas = strfechas.Split(separator);

    DateTime[] fechas1 = new DateTime[fechas.Length];


    for (int i = 0; i < fechas.Length; i++)
    {
        //fechas1[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(fechas[i]);
        fechas1[i] = DateTime.ParseExact(fechas[i], "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    }``
```

Comment: ¿En qué formato te vienen las fechas en el querystring?

Comment: Y que error te da?

Comment: El error es: System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Comment: Y kiko me he estado fijando en la base de datos y las fechas estan guardadas como:"2017-11-28 17:30:22.000", asique ese sera el problema que pense que estaba en otro formato ya que la página web me lo mostraba diferente.

Comment: Sí, el problema es ese. De todas formas, ¿es necesario pasar el string de fechas en el querystring? No es una buena práctica.

Comment: En ese caso, la cadena del parseexact debería ser "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"

Comment: @Igor, [edit] la pregunta e incluye ejemplos de datos que estás pasando por QueryString.

Answer (score 0):

Si el formato deseado es : "días/meses/años horas:minutos"

y en tu base de datos tienes guardado este tipo de formato:

```
"2017-11-28 17:30:22.000"
```

Simplemente debes cambiar el formato a "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff":

```
//    fechas1[i] = DateTime.ParseExact(fechas[i], "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    fechas1[i] = DateTime.ParseExact(fechas[i], "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```